# Css Gradiant not working in internet explorer, when the css flipped

Tags: html, css

I have a gradient css code working in good all browsers

```
header{
padding:0px 0;
   /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+13,3e6d9f+40 */
   background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(0,119,159,0.5) 40%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(13%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#3e6d9f',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}
```

and the image look like this

[image]

then i have to flipped this css for arabic version and the code like

```
header{
padding:0px 0;
   /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+13,3e6d9f+40 */
   background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%, rgba(0,119,159,0.5) 40%) !important; /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(13%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5))) !important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#3e6d9f',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}
```

this code working well all broswers except internet explorer

the image in all broswers flipped like

[image]

but internet explorer showing wrong see the attached image below

[image]

Please help me anybody have faced this issue before , is there any solution for this ? good answers must be appreciated

Comment: I don't quite understand, what does the arabic-version have to do with your problem? Is it working in the english-version? Also which version of IE is causing the problem? Also some html would be helpful also.

Comment: any plunker available?

Comment: @Esko arabic version sites direction different from english

Comment: @JishnuVS I know, but you didn't answer any of my questions...

Comment: ie version `edge and ie10 ` have problem , i dont know why this happening, if i have copy the css in english then the ie will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer the `-ms-linear-gradient` and `linear-gradient` arrange right to left reduce the % to 13

```
header{
   padding:0px 0;
   /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+13,3e6d9f+40 */
   background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%, rgba(0,119,159,0.5) 40%) !important; /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(13%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5))) !important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 87%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to left,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 13%,rgba(62,109,159,0.5) 40%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#3e6d9f',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}
```